# Using Popen inside a process that was created using Popen does nothing

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to open a python script from another without blocking using Popen. The starter script opens the driver script, and (using a tkinter button) the driver script can open a side script. When I try to call Popen in the driver script, nothing happens - the shell opens very briefly then closes. However, when I run the driver script without calling the starter first (as `__main__`), the side script opens fine.

I've posted the code below, am I missing something regarding nested Popen calls? For the executable, I've tried `sys.executable`, `python.exe`, and `pythonw.exe`. None work. Threading might work as an alternative to Popen, but the side script uses tkinter as well, so I would have to find a method for making tkinter thread safe.

starter.py:

```
pid = subprocess.Popen(["pythonw.exe", "driver.py"])
```

driver.py:

```
pid = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "side_script.py"]
```

Comment: "does nothing" is not really a useful description. Inspect the `pid` object (aside: maybe not a great name, since "pid" is a term with a specific meaning) to get the process's state. Did it exit? With what exit status, if so? Is it still running, just not popping up a window?

Comment: Also, if this can't be reproduced with two trivial/near-empty scripts, that means that an answer needs to actually show scripts the issue *does* happen with to be providing a a [mre] for the issue -- essential for anyone to be able to test their answers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Solved the problem looking at error codes. Updated original answer to show.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it! Use the "Add an Answer" button to add your own answer (which you'll later be allowed to accept), instead of editing an answer into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, thankfully it was a simple one. Per Charles Duffy's advice, I tried looking at any errors using output, error = pid.communicate(), and saw there was an error finding the file. I adjusted the code to point to the file using sys.path[0], and it solved the problem.